# Simple response form to generate pdf

Tags: wordpress, forms

I have a quote submission form on my homepage.

When i receive the client email notification i would like to click the link in message  body that lead to a response form.
In this response form i fill the quote description and price.
This generate a pdf quote attached to an email with a prefilled response send to the client.

Maybe WP Fluent forms, sliced invoice or formidable forms can do it ( pro version required ? )

Thank you for you time

A friend of me shown me this solution on a site but i can't see the wp plugin extension on their homepage source.